# How to delete a thousand old glue sessions with ease?

Tags: aws-glue

We (had) about 1500 rows under the Glue `Session History`.

[image: Screenshot of glue session history]

There are many stopped sessions.  I don't think they have any value once stopped.  I mean, you can't restart them.  I'd like to `delete` all the stopped sessions.

Sure, I can change the settings to show 100 per page, and select the lot, and confirm the delete by typing "Delete".  And that gets rid of a few; less than 100, as it gets rate limited.  I'm not sure how long I have to wait to try again.  It's very tedious.

[image: Screenshot of glue session history rate limiting]

Now we can use the aws-cli to delete sessions. Yay.  But only one at a time.
I don't suppose someone has a script already to:

1. fetch `list-sessions` and
2. filter for "stopped" status, and
3. call `delete session` for each one, and
4. avoid the rate limits, and
5. repeat/paginate over all the list pages

Or some other easy way to do it?